# Controller doesn't receive all parameters within the form

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC Web App I am running an ActionResult with the following signature:

```
 Public Function Create(ByVal article As Article_Ad) As ActionResult
```

And in my ASPX page I have declared the following form which fields correspond to the model, which is strongly typed:

```
<%  Using Html.BeginForm(ViewData("action").toString, "Article", FormMethod.Post, New With { .class = "basic"}) %>
<div class="inner-form">
    <%= Html.MyValidationSummary("Por favor corrija os erros e tente novamente.")%> 
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="name">Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o:</label></dt>
        <dd><%= Html.TextBox("description", Model.description, New With {.class = "txt"})%></dd>
        <dt><label for="type">Tipo:</label></dt>
        <dd><%= Html.DropDownList("type", New SelectList(ViewData("typeList"), "value", "text", Model.type), New With {.class = ""})%></dd>
        <dt id="image_dt"></dt>
        <dd id="image_dd">
        <fieldset id="img_fieldset">
        <legend style="font-weight: bold;">Imagem</legend>
        <label for="portrait_image_url">Url da Imagem:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("image_url", Model.image_url, New With {.class = "txt"})%>
        <label for="portrait_bigimage_url">Url da Imagem Portrait:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("portrait_bigimage_url", Model.portrait_bigimage_url, New With {.class = "txt"})%>
        <label for="landscape_bigimage_url">Url da Imagem Landscape:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("landscape_bigimage_url", Model.landscape_bigimage_url, New With {.class = "txt"})%>
        </fieldset>
        </dd>
        <dt id="video_dt"></dt>
        <dd id="video_dd">
        <fieldset id="video_fieldset">
        <legend style="font-weight: bold;">Video</legend>
        <label for="video_url">Url do Video:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("video_url", Model.video_url, New With {.class = "txt"})%>
        <label for="video_fullscreen">Url do Video Fullscreen:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("video_fullscreen", Model.portrait_bigimage_url, New With {.class = "txt"})%>
        </fieldset>
        </dd>
        <dt></dt>
        <dd><input class="button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Gravar" /> <input class="button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Cancelar" /></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<% End Using%>
```

What is happening right now is that when I submit this form, only the description property is assigned to my object. 
I'd like to know why the other properties aren't being filled in my class (I checked with fiddler and everything is being sent correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your properties are in your `Model`.

Also you can make sure you `View` inherits your `Model` to get intellisense for it.

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Your Model)" %>`